# Can't delete app "xcode 5 is in use"

Tags: macos, xcode, trash

I am getting this error emptying my trash after deleting XCode. I don't use it and haven't for years.
It's it possible it is being used by other applications... It seems it's almost part of the OS the way it gets installed?

Or is there another reason? Can I safely delete it somehow? It's quite a few GB!

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer first and then trying immediately?

Comment: Have you rebooted since putting Xcode in the trash?

Comment: yes. Now I see it listed as 0 bytes and I still can't remove it. Trash seems messed up generally